# jQuery maintaining display inline with div show/hide

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is CSS'd to be display: inline;

However, when I use jQuery show/hide, it changes it to block/none.

How can i prevent this and maintain display inline when jQuery shows it?

Comment: Can you not do `.css('display', 'inline')` instead of `show()`?

Comment: may be you can use classes and toggle using jquery

Comment: @AymanSafadi possibly, just was looking for a solution with this method!

Answer (score 0):

You can't afaik.

But what you simply can do is use

```
$('.your-element).css({'display':'inline'});
```

In place of .show().

.hide() can still be used as usual. 
Can't think of anything clever right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown,
>   it will once again be displayed inline.

Is something else going on?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/JdJFJ/

Here is the code snippet from the source:

```
if ( display !== "none" && !jQuery._data( elem, "olddisplay" ) ) {
    jQuery._data( elem, "olddisplay", display );
}
```

Basically, it stores the original `display` in internal data, which is restored on `show()`.  Similar, but different, code exisited all the way back in jQuery 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

@benhowdle89 It seems that this is already possible with jQuery. What version are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, this functionality existed in 1.0.